# 1950s/60s SF Post-Atomic Motorcycle Gang

Tags: story-identification

I read this short story/novelette in an anthology in the 1960s. I don't know when it was originally published, but I suspect it was the '50s. Background: war has destroyed civilization & a motorcycle gang roams the wasteland. Plot: all I can remember is that the MC & a woman somehow anger the gang's leader & have to go on the lam. I can't remember the ending, but one scene sticks in my mind: the fugitives are sitting by a campfire, drinking. The MC (who doesn't have a clue that the woman sitting next to him is in love with him) begins to talk about having a long-term romantic relationship with another gang member. Both she and the reader assume he means *her*, but it turns out the sexist SOB is actually talking about the gang-leader's gorgeous girlfriend!

Comment: I was first thinking of *Damnation Alley* by Roger Zelazney, but too many details fail to match.

Comment: Read this one decades ago, a Damnation Alley knockoff called "The Lost Traveler"  Could this be it? https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/lost-traveler_steve-wilson/1254523/item/13098469/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwtWgBhDhARIsAEMcxeCmiIub0P2NwVuEgftzJ0HZTH04e2EIxBkeaGFPmJa0Y-opBIhzd-0aArCgEALw_wcB#idiq=13098469&edition=2970362

Comment: love 'Damnation Alley' - it's my favorite Zelezny story.  'The Lost Traveler' dates from the 1980s - I readthe story in question in the 1950s.